# If $A$ is any $n×n$ skew symmetric matrix, then$〖 a〗_ii=0,0≤i≤n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is any  $n×n$ skew symmetric matrix, then $〖 a〗_{ii}=0,  0≤i≤n$.
True/False

I just don't understand the problem very well.
what does $〖 a〗_{ii}=0$ refer to?
is the statement true or false?

Comment: Did you put in the 〖〗 symbols or were they present in your source?

Comment: Also: At the level you're working, are the elements of a matrix always real/complex numbers? Or could they belong to an entirely different field or ring? (In particular, skew symmetry works out differently in characteristic 2).

Comment: I tried to put in the equation and the symbols just appeared.
They are always complex/real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s saying that the entries along the main diagonal are 0.  a_ii refers to the i^th row and i^th column which are the diagonal entries.  These are zero because in a skew symmetric matrix you have a_ij=-a_ji and so you have a_ii=-a_ii so a_ii must then be zero.

Comment: so the statement is true?

Comment: @OuilaSaRaH Yes.